# Azure sql server backup to Azure blob - CherrySafe replacement

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage

I am new to Azure SQL server and trying to understand how do I backup Azure SQL databases to Azure blob few times a day.

My company is currently using [Cherry Safe][1] to backup Azure SQL Databases but Cherry Safe is shutting down in 2 weeks.

As I read more about it, it seems like I can configure export to Azure blob but I do not see that option. I see history of exports but I do not know where is the configuration to schedule or change it.

For long term retention, I see an option to configure retention vault.

Are there replacement services out there that Cherry Safe users are using?

Do I need an external service or I can configure the backups myself?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you could backup sql server to azure blob storage, not the azure sql server.

[image]

You could use [SQLBackupAndFTP](https://sqlbackupandftp.com/) to [backup Azure sql database to local machine](https://sqlbackupandftp.com/blog/how-to-backup-and-restore-microsoft-azure-cloud-sql-database).

1.Connect SQLBackupAndFTP to the logical SQL Server in the Azure
[image]
[image]
2.Create a job for regular Azure SQL Database backup
[image]
[image]

Also as you have said, you could use long-term backup retention to backup.
It allows you to preserve weekly, monthly, and yearly backups for an extended period of time up to 10 years.

> Restore a database from a specific long-term backup if the database has been configured with a long-term retention policy. This allows you to restore an old version of the database to satisfy a compliance request or to run an old version of the application. See [Long-term retention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-long-term-retention).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use any third party to backup Azure SQL database, they have much better backup and retention tool on portal. Read this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-long-term-backup-retention-configure